# Compiling NodeJs Module against V8

Tags: c++, node.js, module, v8

I know this has been asked a couple of times recently, however I'm getting a linker error when trying to compile the simplest module example on Ubuntu 13.04

Inspired by the v8 developer website,  I downloaded, compiled and installed nodejs and v8 from source.

I then proceeded to attempt to compile a simple v8 example:

> g++ hello_world.cc -o hello_world -Iinclude out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a -lpthread

The linker errors that I am getting are:

> undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'

along with others within the v8 namespace.

Does anybody have any clue as to what library I am missing?  I have the node.h and v8.h header files included in my path.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you should use node-gyp to build C++ addons

Comment: Your right, I was assuming that I could compile it in eclipse with g++.  Add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use node-gyp tool to build native addons.

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Add a binding.gyp file in addon's root directory. Check here for an example https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file

And then -

```
node-gyp configure

node-gyp build
```